# How to remove all but a few selected files in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to remove all files in a directory except some through a shell script. The name of files will be passed as command line argument and number of arguments may vary.

Suppose the directory has these 5 files:

```
 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt. 4.txt. 5.txt
```

I want to remove two files from it through a shell script using file name.  Also, the number of files may vary.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers, I have figured out my solution. Below is the solution worked for me:

```
find /home/mydir -type f | grep -vw "goo" | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways this *could* be done, but the one that's most robust and highest performance with large directories is probably to construct a `find` command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# first argument is the directory name to search in
dir=$1; shift

# subsequent arguments are filenames to absolve from deletion
find_args=( )
for name; do
  find_args+=( -name "$name" -prune -o )
done

if [[ $dry_run ]]; then
  exec find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 "${find_args[@]}" -print
else
  exec find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 "${find_args[@]}" -exec rm -f -- '{}' +
fi
```

---

Thereafter, to list files which would be deleted (if the above is in a script named `delete-except`):

```
dry_run=1 delete-except /path/to/dir 1.txt 2.txt
```

or, to actually delete those files:

```
delete-except /path/to/dir 1.txt 2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple, straightforward way could be using the GLOBIGNORE variable.

GLOBIGNORE is a colon-separated list of patterns defining the set of filenames to be ignored by pathname expansion. If a filename matched by a pathname expansion pattern also matches one of the patterns in GLOBIGNORE, it is removed from the list of matches.

Thus, the solution is to iterate through the command line args, appending file names to the list. Then call rm *. Don't forget to unset GLOBIGNORE var at the end.

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg in "$@" 
do
    if [ $arg = $1 ]
    then
        GLOBIGNORE=$arg
    else
        GLOBIGNORE=${GLOBIGNORE}:$arg
    fi
done

rm *
unset GLOBIGNORE
```

*In case you had set GLOBIGNORE before, you can just store the val in a tmp var then reset it at the end.

Comment: Please consider testing with filenames with spaces. `[ $arg = $1 ]` is going to behave badly when your name contains whitespace -- and the GLOBIGNORE approach *in general* isn't going to deal well with filenames with colons.

Comment: and btw, there's no reason to `unset GLOBIGNORE` at the end, because when your script exits, all its variables are removed from memory right alongside the process image.

Comment: Also, the explicit loop (and the buggy test) are needless: `IFS=:; GLOBIGNORE="$*"` will do the work of putting your entire argument list into GLOBIGNORE, with colons separating the elements.

Comment: Won't this fail when files to be skipped have `:` in their names?

Answer (score 1):

We can accomplish this in pure Bash, without the need for any external tools:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# build an associative array that contains all the filenames to be preserved
declare -A skip_list
for f in "$@"; do
  skip_list[$f]=1
done

# walk through all files and build an array of files to be deleted
declare -a rm_list
for f in *; do                          # loop through all files
  [[ -f "$f" ]]            || continue  # not a regular file
  [[ "${skip_list[$f]}" ]] && continue  # skip this file
  rm_list+=("$f")                       # now it qualifies for rm
done

# remove the files
printf '%s\0' "${rm_list[@]}" | xargs -0 rm -- # Thanks to Charles' suggestion
```

This solution will also work for files that have whitespaces or glob characters in them.

Comment: I *almost* took an approach that was almost this route, but called `rm` once per file rather than building an array; this is definitely better. That said, at cost of no longer no using external tools other than `rm`, I'd consider `printf '%s\0' "${rm_list[@]}" | xargs -0 rm --` -- that way we're guaranteed that the cutoff will be optimal for the local platform.

Comment: Thanks Charles.  I have updated the answer to incorporate your excellent suggestion.